# Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Application/Org1/Admins when building balance-transfer from fabric samples

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am trying to build Hyperledger network like balanace-transfer from fabric-samples.
I have error

```
status: 'BAD_REQUEST',
-  info: 'Error authorizing update: Error validating DeltaSet: Policy for [Groups] /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining'
```

- `docker logs orderer.exmaple.com` output

.

```
-2018-06-26 14:41:04.631 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 120 Signature set  did not satisfy policy /Channel/Application/Gov1MSP/Admins
-2018-06-26 14:41:04.631 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 121 == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/Gov1MSP/
-2018-06-26 14:41:04.631 UTC [policies] func1 -> DEBU 122 Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ Gov1MSP.Admins ]
-2018-06-26 14:41:04.631 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 123 Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Application/ChannelCreationPolicy
-2018-06-26 14:41:04.631 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 124 == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Application/ChannelCreationPolicy
-2018-06-26 14:41:04.631 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 125 [channel: usachannel] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 172.18.0.1:46638 because of error: Error authorizing update: Error validating DeltaSet: Policy for [Groups] /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining
-2018-06-26 14:41:04.631 UTC [orderer/common/server] func1 -> DEBU 126 Closing Broadcast stream
```

- I generate artifacts with cryptogen and configtxgen
- I know that this error comes with wrong certificates when trying to create a channel
- I can create channel, join peer, add new peers and add new channels with cli, e.g. same step with cli 
  `docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c usachannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx`  **works properly**

Thank you for your help

Comment: You need a signature from Gov1MSP.Admins , not from any other MSP

Comment: Hey @yacovm, thank you for response. 

I am setting admin identity with `client.loadFromConfig(hfc.getConfigSetting('Gov1MSP-connection-profile-path'));`
next I do `client.initCredentialStores`. 

For the 'Gov1MSP-connection-profile-path' i have the following .yaml file.
x-type: "hlfv1"
version: "1.0"
client:
  organization: Gov1MSP
  credentialStore:
    path: "./fabric-client-kv-org1"
    cryptoStore:
      path: "/tmp/fabric-client-kv-org1"
    wallet: wallet-name

So I guess that `credentialStore:path:` should be the file I use with docker exec at CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH ?

Comment: @yacovm or maybe there is some other way to set certificate, before making some transaction with Fabric Node SDK?